# SecureRandom vulnerability also for BouncyCastle C#

Tags: c#, java, security, random, bouncycastle

Today I have heard (through the news) that the Java SecureRandom is not random enough and that it can be predicted. Does this also apply to the SecureRandom implementation in BouncyCastle C#?

[See this news article](http://money.cnn.com/news/newsfeeds/gigaom/articles/2013_08_12_why_bitcoin_users_using_android_wallet_apps_need_to_upgrade.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recent weakness was specifically identified in the Android implementation of `SecureRandom`. Oracle JRE and OpenJDK, have no vulnerabilities in their implementations of `SecureRandom` yet known as far as I can tell. Its worth noting that the implementation of SecureRandom will be different depending on where the JVM is running (i.e. Windows vs Unix-like)

EDIT:
Excerpt from the article link you added, emphasis mine.

> The problem lies in the **Android’s built-in** pseudorandom number
>   generator, the SecureRandom Java class.

Comment: Yes, I did understand that the problem lies in Android, but since it is using the Java SecureRandom class I thought that it also applies to JRE. So what you basicly say is that the code of the SecureRandom class on Android devices is different than the same class in JRE?

Comment: @KeesdeWit Correct. It is a different implementation. There are no Sun/Oracle crypto providers anywhere in Android. In addition, the implementation within a single vendors runtime environment may vary between platform. (i.e. Oracle uses a different `SecureRandom` implementation on Linux than it does on Windows).